# mod-rewrite: Replacing some characters in a url

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to replace some forward slashes (/) of a URL to dots (.) in a RewriteRule? It doesn't have to be done exclusively with a RewriteRule, but definitely not with a script.

Example 1:

```
INPUT:  /document/my/document.html
OUTPUT: /document-my.document.html
```

Example 2:

```
INPUT:  /document/depth/of/path/can/vary.html
OUTPUT: /document-depth.of.path.can.vary.html
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you could do this, using an iterative approach. The "variable number of replacements" means you must use the same rule several times, one for each "/" to replace.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$1.$2 [N]
```

Some details:

- The pattern matches `/` + anything + `/` + anything
- You need to match the first `/`explicitely, because it will always be there and mustn't be replaced with a `.`
- The `[N]` flag means: `Re-run the rewriting process (starting again with the first rewriting rule). This time, the URL to match is no longer the original URL, but rather the URL returned by the last rewriting rule.` (from the [Apache mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule))

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! I've just added a few minor tweaks (above) to complete it.

Answer (score 0):

What worked (thanks to Jonathan Clarke's answer):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/document.*
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$1.$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^/document\.(.*)\.html /document-$1 [L]
```