# Rewrite URLs in apache with &amp; in the query

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, httpd

I am trying to construct a rewrite condition and rule to rewrite URLs with &amp; in the query string, rather than just &. This has occurred because of some invalid encoding when the URL is transmitted to a client in XML. Long term that will be fixed, but short term if I can put a rewrite rule in place it will stop 404 errors.

An example URL is

https://myserver.com/getpdf/download?md5=53d64aee8107d8f8af0c&amp;id=163464591&amp;tz=GMT

So far I have got this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/getpdf/download*
RewriteRule ^/([^&]+)(&amp;)(.*)$ /$1&$2 [N]
```

based on other posts on serverfault (eg [mod-rewrite: Replacing some characters in a url](https://serverfault.com/questions/122321/mod-rewrite-replacing-some-characters-in-a-url))

I turned on the rewrite log and this is what I see

```
10.0.0.64 - - [12/Mar/2016:06:42:52 +0000] [myserver.com/sid#7f24e32103e8][rid#7f24e3379870/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /getpdf/download
10.0.0.64 - - [12/Mar/2016:06:42:52 +0000] [myserver.com/sid#7f24e32103e8][rid#7f24e3379870/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(md5)([^&]+)(&amp;)(.*)$' to uri '/getpdf/download'
10.0.0.64 - - [12/Mar/2016:06:42:52 +0000] [myserver.com/sid#7f24e32103e8][rid#7f24e3379870/initial] (1) pass through /getpdf/download
```

Any guidance on how to correctly form the rewriterule would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Teros answer pointing me in the right direction I solved my rewrite rule.

First step was to match against %{QUERY_STRING}.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^md5=([0-9a-f])(&)id=([0-9])(&)(.*)$
```

And the second step was to rewrite the entire URL. My mistake was in thinking that I could modify only the query string.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://myserver.com/getpdf/download?md5=%1&id=%3&%5 [N]
```

Some tips

- %1 in the RewriteRule uses groups from the RewriteCond
- $1 would use groups from the regex in the RewriteRule instead
- Rewrite uses Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE). I used this tester to check my regex - https://regex101.com/#pcre
- Google "Learn Apache mod_rewrite: 13 Real-world Examples"
- The apache intro to rewrite, and the image showing the basics, helps - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/intro.html (essentially a case of RTFM :) )

Hope this helps others lost in the world of rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Apache documentation states that if you want to rewrite query string part of the URI, then you need to use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`.

So, you should try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} md5=([0-9a-f]{20}(&amp;)(id=[0-9]+)(&amp;)(.*)
RewriteRule ^md5=([0-9a-f]{20}(&amp;)id=([0-9]+)(&amp;)(.*)$ md5=$1&id=$2&$3 [N]
```

Comment: Tero, thanks for your pointers. The answer needed some more tweaking, I'm going to post the solution now.